# Symfony2 get values from entity oneToMany related to another oneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities relates as following : 
A (oneToMany) B (oneToMany) C
how could I get all records from C that based on an A->id  ???????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); // or however you instance Entitymanager

$entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('entityC', 'c')
    ->join('c.entityB', 'b')
    ->join('b.entityA', 'a')
    ->where('a = :entityA')
    ->setParameter('entityA', $yourAEntityHere)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: thanks a lot for coming to the rescue, but let ask you, isn't it go nna give C results for just one of the B records, but not all B records???